# How to determine the backup source

Tags: sql-server, backup, debugging

We are trying to identify what is taking a SQL backup. The physical device name is just a guid which I have seen before when using a VSS type backup but I don't see any backup agent software installed on the host and there are no maintenance plans or jobs running any backups so we are kinda stumped. We are going to try and use Wireshark to see if we can determine anything. Anyone have any ideas about identifying what is running the backup? See screenshot of the backup. Thanks[image]

12/22/2022 04:47:55,spid60,Unknown,I/O is frozen on database msdb. No user action is required. However if I/O is not resumed promptly you could cancel the backup.

Comment: Is the server a virtual machine? If it is, it's pretty likely a VM host level backup.

Comment: Do you see "SQL Server has frozen the IO" in your SQL Server log ?
If you do, it may be an OS backup (no local agent required) that is taking the SQL backup)

Comment: It's possible to turn on VSS logging and see what is being invoked at that time. If it's a physical machine this should be easier to track down, if it's a VM then good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, It is a VM and I do see the freeze & thaw entries in the SQL Log when the backup happens.